# Tags for Google Cloud observability tool - [stackdriver] and [google-cloud-stackdriver]

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

Google had [purchased Stackdriver](https://techcrunch.com/2014/05/07/google-acquires-cloud-monitoring-service-stackdriver/) 5 years ago, so it does not make sense to distinguish "google" and "non-google" versions of the tag.

Right now:

- [google-cloud-stackdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-stackdriver) (400+ questions) is just a less popular version of [stackdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackdriver) (700+ questions).
- [stackdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackdriver) has tag description, while other does not

Proposal: **[google-cloud-stackdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-stackdriver) should be a synonym to [stackdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackdriver)**.

---

*Disclaimer: I work on this product.*